# Texture appear stretched despites UV unwrap and applying all transforms

Tags: texturing, uv

I've tried unwraping as well as applying all transforms yet my texture still appear stretched. What am I missing here ?

[image: My UV Map & viewport]

[image: My shader editor]

Comment: hello, please show your Shader Editor

Comment: @moonboots Hello, I added it!

Comment: so first thing, try the UV output of your Texture Coordinate, for the moment your UVs are not taken into account

Comment: That seems to have solved my issue, thank you very much @moonboots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the UV unwrap you've created, use the *UV* output of your *Texture Coordinate* instead of the *Generated*.